# Arraylist.add() is overwriting all the values in the Arraylist built by a loop in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist

Arraylist.add() is overwriting all the previous values in the Arraylist built by a loop in c#. The code is:

```
public ArrayList MakeList(int size,  int iterations)
{
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList(iterations);

    for (int run = 0; run < iterations; run++)
    {
        byte[] _byteArray = new byte[size];
        bool success = false;
        while (!success)
        {
            //Some Operations 
            if(condition)
               success = true;
           else 
              continue;
            if(success)
              break;

        }
        myList .Add(_byteArray );
    }

    return myList;
}
```

The above loop always overwriting the values in the List with the latest byte array. Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "overwriting"? `ArrayList myList = new ArrayList(iterations);` --- it is empty here. So there is nothing to *overwrite*

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ArrayList` to start with. Use generic `T[]` array or `List<T>`. It's not 2003 anymore...

Comment: Side note: `success = true` without any condition in the loop. Means just one loop iteration you got there. Still your question is not complete.

Comment: I have a feeling that the OP have tried to simplify the code to make it an easy question to read, but on the way removed some critical code lines...

Comment: The posted code shows no obvious errors. Try to create a small but complete (console) application that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: _I have a feeling that the OP have tried to simplify the code to make it an easy question to read, but on the way removed some critical code lines..._ Looking at the extra spaca in `myList .Add(_byteArray );` I have to agree..

Comment: The edits don't really help. You'll need to state where\when\how the 'overwriting' happens because this code doesn't show that.

Answer (score 0):

Karthick initially I thought it to be an issue of deep copy or shallow copy but as long as you are initializing the byte array inside the for loop it should work perfectly.  I tried following sample code at my end and it works perfectly fine when function MakeList is about to return. Three byte arrays pointed by myList contain 00,01,11 as I've inserted them and there is no overwriting as suggested by you. I've hardcoded few parameters for quick output:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var col = new ColTest();
            col.MakeList();
         }        
}

public class ColTest
    {
        public ArrayList MakeList()
        {
            var capacity = 3;
            ArrayList myList = new ArrayList(capacity);
            int size = 2;
            for (int run = 0; run < capacity; run++)
            {
                byte[] _byteArray = new byte[size];

                if (run == 0)
                {
                    _byteArray[0] = 0;
                    _byteArray[1] = 0;
                }
                else if (run == 1)
                {
                    _byteArray[0] = 0;
                    _byteArray[1] = 1;
                }
                else if (run == 2)
                {
                    _byteArray[0] = 1;
                    _byteArray[1] = 1;
                }

                myList.Add(_byteArray);
            }

            return myList;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!